# Can't get resource image from file: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null

Tags: java, resources

```
projectname
  src
    main
      resources
         Picture.gif
    test
      Test.java
```

**Test.java**:

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test = new Test();
        test.imageLoad();
    }

    public void imageLoad()  {
        try {
            BufferedImage image = ImageIO
                    .read(getClass()
    .getResource("/resources/Picture.gif"));

        }
        catch (Exception e)  {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

running the Test.main gives

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1388)
```

at line

```
.read(getClass()
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9864267/loading-image-resource).

Comment: It’s just `getResource("/Picture.gif")`.  src/main/resources is the root of the included resources.